# Resizing images (in SVG format) after applying "rotate" transformation

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I've been working on an application that allows users to add images to a viewport, then resize them, crop them and rotate them. For the rotation to work, the images are added as SVG's, using the Raphael.js library.

All images have an outline (called ***wrapper***). When an image is resized, so is its wrapper. When the image is rotated, the wrapper expands too, so that it will contain the rotated image (see image bellow).

[image: Image contained within its wrapper]

So far, so good. Except that when I attempt to resize an image object AFTER it has been rotated, it won't be contained within its outline anymore (see image bellow).

[image: Image resized, after it has been rotated]

When resizing an image, the svg oject's "x" and "y" attributes also need to be adjusted. Both the new size (width + height) of the image and the "x" and "y" attributes are computed as seen bellow:

```
var ratio_width = w / init.wrapper.width,         // w = the new width of the wrapper (computed at each resize step)
    ratio_height = h / init.wrapper.height,       // h = the new height of the wrapper

    svg_width = init.svg.width * ratio_width,     // svg_width = the new width of the image
    svg_height = init.svg.height * ratio_height,  // svg_height = the new height of the image

    x = init.svg.x*ratio_width,
    y = init.svg.y*ratio_height;

this.svg.attr({
    "x": x,
    "y": y,
    "width": svg_width,
    "height": svg_height
});
```

The "init" JavaScript object contains the size (width & height) of the wrapper AND the size of the image (after the image is rotated, their dimensions will differ), but also the values of the *x* and *y* attributes BEFORE the resize operation.

The thing is that all the values computed above are correct. I know because I've also tried destroying the svg at each resize step and re-appending it (but it's not an option, there's too much of a flicker), with those same values for size, *x* and *y*, like so:

```
// "this.angle" on the second line is the current rotation angle
this.svg.remove();
this.svg = this.canvas.image(this.src,x,y,svg_width,svg_height).transform("r"+this.angle);
```

So if I simply remove the object and then create it again with the values above, why won't simply changing its attributes do the job as it should? I've been pulling my hair out for 3 days now, so I'd appreciate some help!

Comment: Please don't add tags to the title, that's what the tags section is for.

Comment: I added "Raphael.js" because it's important for users to know what kind of transformations I'm referring to.

Comment: I feel you, but I think it's enough with the tag in the tags section =)

Comment: Well, I've applied a change after your message. Anyway, do you have any ideas about the problem?

Comment: Nope, sorry, Raphael.js is not really my area =/

Comment: Which point is used as a center of rotation?

Comment: By default, the center of the image is also the center of rotation.

Comment: There's a Raphael plugin for this, you might want to look at the source code and see how the transform + scale is done: https://github.com/ElbertF/Raphael.FreeTransform

Comment: Should that wrapper rectangle follow the transformation of image? I mean when image is rotated, the wrapper rotates as well. Usually in vector editors it follows (with the exception of line-scaling of wrapper and scaling of corner handles).